# How to use type–converting comparison instead of strict in switch Javascript?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Is there a way in Javascript to use the non-strict comparison in a switch statement ?

Example:

```
if (item == '3') { ... }
else if (item == 'Chocolate') { ... }
else { ... }
```

In a switch:

```
switch (item){
    case '3':
        ... break;
    case 'Chocolate':
        ... break;
    default:
        ...
}
```

I would like to test if *item* equals **3** (number) or **'3'** (char) in one case. I would like to avoid to write two cases for the same instructions.

Is it possible ?

Comment: No, AFAIK it's not. Switches always use strict comparison.

Comment: `switch(item){ ... case '3': case 3: {/* do stuff*/ break;} ...}` You can have case `'3'` fall through to case `3` so they execute the same code

Comment: how about `switch(item.toString()){ ...` ? I think toString() is the go-to comparison method of JS

Comment: @mhodges Not exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: or use fallthrough as @mhodges suggests

Comment: No, it's not possible. What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), why don't you know the types of your variables?

Comment: @Boris have to test yours in different cases!
As I said, mhodges solution is good, but I don't want to write multiple cases
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460824/how-to-use-type-converting-comparison-instead-of-strict-in-switch-javascript?noredirect=1#comment75918330_44460892

Comment: @Bergi because I could use this switch for different actions in my script :)

Comment: Did you consider `const actions = {'3': doSomething, '4': doSomethingElse}; action[item]();`? - Leveraging objects / maps to that extend is somewhat idiomatic in JS. Just be careful about special cases such as `item == -0`.

Comment: @Zooly What's an "action"? And why doesn't it have a consistent type?

Comment: Action -> Instructions. Because i want to use this switch in few functions. I don't want to duplicate my code, and sometimes, a switch case can be the same, but with a type depending of which function called

Comment: That's still no excuse for using different value types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
switch(item.toString()){
   case "3" :
       [...]
```

will behave as you want. it is a little hacky but it works.

As seen in comments below, there are many caveats to this however. It will work exactly as intended if you are sure that item is always a string or number.

booleans will be, well `"true"` or `"false"`, and as such not fall into "0" and "1" cases.

objects, unless you have changed their toString method, will fall in a `"[object Object]"` case.

Arrays of one element will "toString" into the same case as their only elements.

I'll reiterate that you're probably way safer with using fall-through.

#### With that said... let's go into whacky territory

I've tried to override Object.prototype.valueOf as can be seen in [fake-operator-overloading](http://2ality.com/2011/12/fake-operator-overloading.html). the switch statement, however, doesn't call valueOf, so that's off the table. Now if you REALLY want the `switch` semantics AND an `==`, you can do this :

```
switch(true){
    case key == 1 :
        //...
        break;
    case key == "something" :
        //...
        break;
    case key == false :
        //...
        break;
    default :
}
```

[this method taken from mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Can_I_use_switch_to_simplify_multiple_if's)

Now, to me that seems very complex for not a lot of bonus. but here you have it. I'm not even sure what case would some values such as `{}` or `NaN` fall into, but for example `""` and `0` would go into `false`provided nothing catches them before

Comment: One example of strange behavior that I can think of off the top of my head is if `item = [3]` or `item=["3"]`, it will hit the `case "3"` code.

Comment: definitely many ways it can go wrong. if they know for sure item will always be a Number, bool or string, it will work :).

Comment: for more complex scenarios, well, fallthrough seems the best way. Or maybe a `switchableize(item)` function that they can tweak to their content ?

Comment: @Boris Actually it doesn't work on booleans like `==` does. You might want to include the restrictions in your answer

Comment: True, I'll do that !

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this (It's called fall-through):

```
switch (item){
    case '3':
    case 3:
        ... break;
    case 'Chocolate':
        ... break;
    default:
        ...
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it could well work, but I really would like to avoid to write multiple cases for the "same thing". No way to ignore var type in a switch ?